# App Script Conditional Formatting on multiple Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using this App Script to apply Conditional Formatting on single sheet.

I would like to apply this conditional formatting to multiple sheets. I am striving hard to find a way like this below line where i would add sheet name and conditional formatting will start working on those sheets which have been added in the code.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

**something like this**

```
["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7"];


function formatting() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dec');
  const range = sheet.getRange("C1:AG"+sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();
  const bcolors = range.getBackgrounds();
  const new_bcolors = values.map((r,i)=>r.map((c,j)=>c=='L'?'#ea9999':bcolors[i][j]))
  range.setBackgrounds(new_bcolors)
 }
```

Comment: You want to copy the format or the conditional formatting rules? Because your code tries to copy only the background colors (format)

Comment: Yes the format color if all sheets Range("C1:AG") has this value  "L" then it should paste the the format as above code does.

Comment: Hey there @Strenous, has your issue been resolved? If not - would you mind providing more details about the use of the `onEdit` trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to apply a specific conditional formatting on a selection of sheets.

I believe, constructing the conditional formatting for each sheet would be faster than iterating over each cell for every sheet to check for the value "L" and then set the background color of that cell. Also this approach wouldn't be dynamic because you change the format, not the conditional formatting. Namely, if you change "L" to something else e.g. "M" the cell format will stay until you run the script again.

The idea of the following script is to use the [ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder) class and the steps are:

- The rule is: if the value of the cell is equal to "L" then apply the color `#ea9999`.
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) sheet in the document check if the name is [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the selected array of sheet names `sheetsNames`.
- If it does, then construct the following conditional formatting:

  ```
  SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
               .whenTextEqualTo("L")
               .setBackground("#ea9999")
               .setRanges([range])
               .build();
  ```

### Solution:

```
function copyConditional(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetsNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", 
                       "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7"];
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{
       if (sheetsNames.includes(sh.getName())){
           console.log(sh.getName())
           let range = sh.getRange("C1:AG"+sh.getMaxRows());  
           let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
                   .whenTextEqualTo("L")
                   .setBackground("#ea9999")
                   .setRanges([range])
                   .build();
           let rules = sh.getConditionalFormatRules();
           rules.push(rule);
           sh.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
       }})                   
}
```

Comment: You mean i should use the conditional formatting for each sheet separately to make it faster.

Comment: @Strenuous Glad your issue was resolved. Improved my explanation a little bit.

Comment: @ Yes you are proved as always helpful.

Comment: Yes @Marios you were right it is extremely slow is there any way to do this thing via Built in Conditional formatting function using single formula by mentioning each sheet name.

Comment: Range (C1:AG) then Text is exactly "L" then format on these sheets ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

Comment: @Strenuous yes add these sheet names to `sheetsNames` and try it out. It should work.

Comment: Yes i did and it took me approx 8 minutes to complete that function the problem is when i would add trigger on edit and whenever i will add anything in sheet it will take 8 minutes each time

Comment: @Strenuous why would you want to execute this code with an onEdit trigger? the conditional formatting rule is going to to be effective forever unless you change it everytime. What is the purpose of the `onEdit` trigger?

Comment: Ok i was not aware that it will work automatically i mean without trigger. If it does i will not use the trigger

Comment: @Strenuous I changed the code to apply the conditional formatting all the way to the bottom of each sheet (full sheet range `C1:AG`). As soon as the conditional formatting is set, it will stay forever there unless you delete it or change it. So there is no need to "update" it with an `onEdit` trigger.